# AusMap plugin loading/install error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, australia, macos

I receive the following error running 3.8 on macOS High Sierra - thoughts?

```
Couldn't load plugin 'AusMap' due to an error when calling its initGui() method
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_groups_with_layers'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 359, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "/Users/new/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/AusMap/aus_map.py", line 111, in initGui
    self.createMenu()
  File "/Users/new/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/AusMap/aus_map.py", line 131, in createMenu
    self.config.load()
  File "/Users/new/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/AusMap/config.py", line 29, in load
    self.am_config.load()
  File "/Users/new/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/AusMap/am_config.py", line 41, in load
    self.background_category, self.categories = self.get_kf_categories()
  File "/Users/new/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/AusMap/am_config.py", line 55, in get_kf_categories
    groups_with_layers = self.kf_qlr_file.get_groups_with_layers()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_groups_with_layers'
```

Comment: A similar bug was reported at the plugin's github page with a potential solution. Have you checked this page: https://github.com/WaterModellingSolutions/AusMap/issues/11?